# gulp-nodemon watcher does not work

Tags: node.js, gulp

i'm developing a websocket server, I tried to restart the server with nodemon as soon as i change it. However it appears that this is not working for me.

```
gulp.task('startWebsocketServer', function() {
  return nodemon({
    script: './server/websocket/server.js',
    watch: ['./server/websocket/**/*.js']
  });
});
```

Does anyone have an idea what i did wrong here?

nodemon is on version 1.9.2 and nodejs on 4.2.6.

Comment: Try adding ` DEBUG=nodemon* ` env variable when running gulp. This will   give you some idea if files are being watched properly.

Comment: Thanks, it was at least helpful to knew this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gulp-nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nodemon) inherits its options from [`nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon). Concerning the `watch` option [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon#monitoring-multiple-directories)  say this:

> By default nodemon will traverse sub-directories, so there's no need in explicitly including sub-directories. [...] Don't use unix globbing to pass multiple directories, e.g --watch ./lib/*, it won't work

So can't and don't need to use a globstar `**` in your `watch` option. Simply specifying the directory should suffice:

```
gulp.task('startWebsocketServer', function() {
  return nodemon({
    script: './server/websocket/server.js',
    watch: ['./server/websocket']
  });
});
```